# Refactoring weirdly branching method

Tags: python

let's say we have a function like this.

```
def do_smth():
      x = get_x()
      if x is None:
          return False
      y = get_y(x)
      if y is None:
          return False
      do_smth_else(x,y)

def do_smth_else(x,y)
    ....
```

This works just fine, but I'm not big fan of this weird branching. Do you have any suggestions how to refactor it?

Comment: Is this the entirety of the function? So if `get_x` or `get_y` is `None` you return `False`, otherwise `None`?  Something like `return None if get_x() and get_y() else False`.  This won't work if you expect falsey values from `get_x` or `get_y`.  For that you would need `return None if get_x() is not None and get_y() is not None else False`

Comment: There's more happening after those checks. and get_y() might depend on get_x()

Comment: @JukesOnYou: Can you edit your code to incorporate all of the relationships between these variables and functions?

Comment: @Blender Yep just did it

Comment: @JukesOnYou: Can you remove the `None` checks on `x` and `y` and allow the resulting exceptions to happen? Otherwise, I don't really see a way to simplify this code.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code as you have it now.  The alternative to that approach is to put the remainder of the function body inside a nested `if` statement.

```
def do_smth():
    x = get_x()
    if x:
        y = get_y(x)
        if y:
            do_smth_else(x,y)
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False

def do_smth_else(x,y)
    ....
```

The way you are using is preferable to the unnecessarily indented code.

Comment: @JukesOnYou That was my point.  The way you have it currently is better than the alternative,

Answer (score -3):

You could do it like this.

```
def do_smth():
      x = get_x()
      y = get_y(x) if x else False 
      return do_smth_else(x, y) if x else False
```

Comment: This doesn't short circuit in the event of a `None` `get_x`.  What if `get_y(None)` throws errors?  `x and y is not None` does not do what I suspect you think it does

Comment: if get_x or get_y returns none then this function returns False.

Comment: Try this with `def get_x(): return 0` and `def get_y(x): return x`.  Or `get_x(): return None` and `get_y(x): return x*2`.

Comment: Which of the first example returns `None`? I would expect it to return the result of `do_smth_else(0, 0)` I doubt the second example executes to completion because `None*2` is a `TypeError`.

Comment: sorry! I have edited my answer.. maybe better?  with def get_x():
    return None

def get_y(x):
    return x * 2